# objective-c How to cache images from facebook using SDWebImage?

Tags: objective-c, caching, tableview, sdwebimage

Im new in iOS programming so i need some help.
 I have a TableViewController with a property NSArray, where is stored Facebook User's friends info: **uid**, **square_pic** and **name**. I use to load their profile photos using FBProfilePictureView, by uid. 
 My problem:   When user scroll the table pictures from cells take a lot of time to reload. I want to **cache** this photos using **SDWebImage**.
  Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar to SDWebImage. Their readme mentions ability to cache, so you might want to figure it out on your own.

However, there is a really nice class called [NSCache](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that you can implement in some of your managers or view controllers. Also, [this](http://nshipster.com/nscache/) post by Mattt Thompson covers it in great details.
It functions as a regular NSDictionary in sense that you can set object for keys and retrieve them. e.g:

```
    //setting
    [cache setObject:image forKey:@"yourImageURL"]


    //accessing
    UIImage *image = [cache objectForKey:@"yourImageURL"];
    if (image == nil) {
       // request it 
    }
```

But it also contains some awesome staff for setting values for objects which will serve as a hint which objects have to be removed in case of low memory.

Hope this helps to answer your question.
Cheers!